# How to create Widget using Sencha Touch 2 (Native Packaging)?

Tags: php, mysql, sencha-touch-2

I am newbie to Sencha Touch 2 and have created a basic applications using sencha and PHP/MySQL as backend. Currently I'm accessing web services through mobile web browser.

Is there any way we can create Widget of application like "AndroidMarket" so user can access it without any web browser?

If yes, is there any link or tutorial?

Comment: what do you mean by `Widget`? Do you mean native packaging?

Comment: yes Exactly I just find out what it call its "native packaging" :).
how to do it ? any reference or tutorials ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good place to start with:

[Sencha Touch 2 Native Packaging for Android](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_android)